# How to write our own DiagnosticConsumer in clang libtooling?

Tags: c++, clang, libtooling

I want to capture the source files error and warnings when I give it as a input to my libtooling tool.

For example consider the program

main.c

```
int main()
{
   printf("hello");
   return 0;
}
```

so clang throws warning `implicitly declaring library function 'printf' with type 'int'.`

How to capture these warnings in clang libtooling with `DiagnosticConsumer`?